# using <option> in combination of mysql to change values

Tags: php, mysql

For my job i am creating a webpage to register our products on stock.
I made it able to create new users which are saved in a mysql database.

I use values from the database for the users to choose from which works:

```
<select class="form-control" type="text" name="vestiging">
<option></option>
<?php $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT vestigingnaam FROM vestiging;");
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
while ($row1) {
print ("<option>" . $row1["vestigingnaam"] . "</option>");
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
}
?>
</select>
```

I would like to be able to edit this profiles and change their atributes.
For this i tried to use the folowing code:

```
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT mannr, login, password, naam, vestiging, rol, status FROM gebruiker
                            WHERE mannr = '" . ($_GET["id"]) . "';");
                            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                            if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0) {    

    print ("<div class=\"form-group\">");
                print ("<label for=\"vestiging\">Vestiging</label>");
               print ("<select class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"vestiging\">");
               print ("<option>" . ($row["vestiging"]) . "</option>");
                    $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT vestigingnaam FROM vestiging;");
                    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
                    while ($row1) {
                    print ("<option>" . $row3["vestigingnaam"] . "</option>");
                    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
                    print ("</select>");
                    print ("</div>");
        }

print ("<div class=\"form-group\">");
    print ("<label for=\"userrole\">Functie rol</label>");
   print ("<select class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"userrole\">");
   print ("<option>" . ($row["rol"]) . "</option>");
        $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT rolnaam FROM rol;");
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
        while ($row2) {
        print ("<option>" . $row3["rolnaam"] . "</option>");
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
        print ("</select>");
        print ("</div>");
        }

    }
```

The thing that goes wrong is that when i let the user select multiple of the selection boxes by using multiple query's for each selection field (query1 query2 etc.) the selection boxes result in nothing.

Comment: Sorry, should have suplied some more background and code, see above

Comment: just from skimming over your code: you are using the variable `$row3` without ever creating it, you are iterating over `row2`and inside that loop you are reassigning that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!
Martin: indeed correct i made a typo on the $row3

Other than that is made a mistake on the while part:

```
while ($row2) {
        print ("<option>" . $row3["rolnaam"] . "</option>");
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
        print ("</select>");
        print ("</div>");
        }
```

should be

```
while ($row2) {
        print ("<option>" . $row3["rolnaam"] . "</option>");
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
        }
print ("</select>");
print ("</div>");
```

Comment: It's still bad to assing a value to the Array you are looping through and will lead to errors or unexpected behaviour